# Spinner getChildCount() and getChildAt() error

Tags: java, android, spinner

I populate **Spinner(SpinnerPrac)** from **ArrayList(listaprac)**. Spinner work fine, but i'd like to `setTextColor` for last element.

This is my adapter

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinneritem, listaprac);
         dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner); 
         SpinnerPrac.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

I think i should use `getChildAt(listaprac.size())` method and set color like this:

```
((TextView) SpinnerPrac.getChildAt(listaprac.size())).setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
```

But it returns null pointer exception.

I tried return ChildCount
`SpinnerPrac.getChildCount()` but returns 0. Why is it happening ? I have 6 item in `spinner`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you can't do this in `getView` method of `ArrayAdapter`. Check the position and If it matches the list size change the color of the `View`

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(position == list.size() - 1){
        convertView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

Comment: what parameters should i use ? position is for example 1, what is it convertview and parent ?

Comment: convertView is the View you are seeing inside the Spinner. Position is index of that view.

Comment: so it is textview, and parent. Is SpinnerPrac parent?

Comment: Yeah parent will be the spinner(AdapterView)

Comment: i created adapter in separate class ans then use your method for ArrayAdapter, and now it works, thx

Answer (score 0):

The index of the last element is `listaprac.size() - 1` not `listaprac.size()`.

Comment: i tried this, is not working, something is wrong with use this syntax, because getChildCount retruns 0